# Is this animation a homotopy?

Tags: homotopy-theory

I refer to the animation shown in this Wikipedia website of a homeomorphism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism

In fact, it is claimed that this animation depicts a continuous deformation (in fact it appears as though it illustrates a strong deformation retraction) between a torus and a mug. However I find this animation rather misleading in illustrating a homotopy. We shall consider the base of the mug to be a closed disk of radius 1 centred at the origin on the $xy$ plane, and assume that the standard topology be used at all times for purposes of this discussion. If one were to scrutinise the transition from a torus to a mug, which is to represent a homotopy $H:S^1\times S^1\times I\rightarrow M$ where $M = D^2\times 0\cup S^1\times I\cup K$ (where $K$ is the handle of the mug which is not of concern in this question), let $t^{'}\in I$ be the time $t^{'}$ where the torus is mapped to the solid defined by $D^2\times I$. Restricting $H$ to $S^1\times S^1\times [t^{'},1]$, which we denote by $H^{*}$, by assertion that $H$ is continuous then so is $H^{*}$. We transform $H^{*}$ linearly such that $H^{*}:D^2\times I\times I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ is a homotopy. Since $D^2\times I\cup K$and the torus is homeomorphic, with homeomorphism $p: D^2\times I\rightarrow S^1\times S^1$, the map $H^{*}\circ p\times Id_I: D^2\times I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ should also be continuous. With the standard topology endowed the standard tools of analysis are applicable. Consider any small neighbourhood centred at $(1,0,1,s)$ for $s\centernot=0,s\in I$. Wouldnt we be able to find a sufficiently small $\epsilon$ such that there exists such that no $\delta$ exists whereby whenever $||k-(1,0,1,s)||<\delta$, $||H(k)-H(1,0,1,s)||<\epsilon$?. Intuitively and loosely speaking, I cannot convince myself that the animation is continuous, as a chunk of solid is being vertically pushed down from $D^2\times I$.

Note that we modeled the mug to be of negliglble thickness. Since $D^2$ is connected we may change the argument to a mug with thickness without altering the purposes of this question. I visualise the deformation to motivare the construction of proposed homotopies and hence I feel this question is worth asking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please feel free to point out any mistakes in the construction, or if this question is not suitable for Stackexchange,, if my wording is unclear or contradictory or if the above argument is invalid and the animation is an accurate representation of a homotopy please explain why. Any constructive feedback is welcomed.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You consider wrongly the mug as a surface, while it is clear from the figure that it is a solid body, and the displayed surface is the external surface of this body. So, if the handle of the mug would be removed, this surface could be defined as
$$\begin{align}
&\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2\le 10,\quad z=0\}\\
\cup\quad&\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2\le 9,\quad z=1\}\\
\cup\quad&\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2=10,\quad 0\le z\le 10\}\\
\cup\quad&\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2=9,\quad 1\le z\le 10\}\\
\cup\quad&\{(x,y,z)\mid 9\le x^2+y^2\le 10,\quad z=10\}
\end{align}$$ 
So, the first step of the animation is the homotopy for which the surface, at time $0\le t\le 1$ is:
$$\begin{align}
&\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2\le 10,\quad z=0\}\\
\cup\quad&\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2\le 9,\quad z=1+t(10-1)\}\\
\cup\quad&\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2=10,\quad 0\le z\le 10\}\\
\cup\quad&\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2=9,\quad 1+t(10-1)\le z\le 10\}\\
\cup\quad&\{(x,y,z)\mid 9\le x^2+y^2\le 10,\quad z=10\}
\end{align}$$ 
Can you be clearer about your concern with this homotopy?

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. With your equations provided I can visualise now understand what you meant. Sorry for the confusion.